# x^y calculator Button - in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
   `String calcHistory = "";
    String SavedCalcHistory = "";
    String result = "";
    String equation = "";
    String baseNum = "";
    double num;
    Boolean exponentFlag = false;`

private void digits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        equation += b.Text;
        textBox1.Text += b.Text;
    }

private void ExponentInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baseNum = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        exponentFlag = true;
    }

private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = equation;
        result = new DataTable().Compute(result, null).ToString();
        calcHistory += equation + " = " + result + "\n";
        textBox1.Text = result;
        if(exponentFlag == true)
        {
            num = Convert.ToDouble(baseNum);
            double expo = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = Math.Pow(num, expo).ToString();
        }
        exponentFlag = false;
    }
```

Digit_click is referenced on the number buttons.

Exponent_Click is referenced on x^y button. User input a number, clicks x^y button, inputs number (exponent)

on hitting = button, if Exponent flag in equals_click is true, convert first input and second input into double and pass to Math.Pow(). convert result to String and display in textbox.

Only one text field.

2^2 is giving me 419,000.

Comment: You only need *ONE* event handler.  Like an "x^y button" if you want.  And two text fields: one for your "number", the other for your "exponent".  When somebody clicks the button, then 1) read the number text field, and convert it to a numeric value (with appropriate error handling, if the conversion fails). 2) Read the exponent, and convert to a number (presumably an "int").  3) Compute Math.Pow() and display the results.  *BE SURE TO TEST WITH YOUR DEBUGGER*!!!

Comment: Note that `equation` will be 22 when you click `=`, so you calculate `2 ^ 22 = 4.194.304`.

Comment: only one text field available

Comment: thanks Klaus! i got it to work after you made that clear. I saw that in calc history but didn't think it was actually calculating 2^22 -_____- much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The check for the exponent flag needs to be first - before you calculate the result. Also, `calcHistory` probably needs to be updated correctly as well.

```cs
private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (exponentFlag == true)
    {
        num = Convert.ToDouble(baseNum);
        double expo = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        result = Math.Pow(num, expo).ToString();
        exponentFlag = false;
        equation = "" + baseNum + "^" + expo;
    }
    else
    {
        result = equation;
        result = new DataTable().Compute(result, null).ToString();
    }
    textBox1.Text = result;
    calcHistory += equation + " = " + result + "\n";
}
```

Other notes:

- you really want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), especially how to use a debugger and set breakpoints so that you can see step by step what is happening.
- use `string` instead of `String`
- use `bool` instead of `Boolean`
- `if (exponentFlag == true)` is the same as `if (exponentFlag)`
- things like `result = exponent` is confusing, because the exponent is clearly not the result.
- `num` could be a local variable

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have **textBox1** for **integer1** and **textBox2** for **integer2**.
You have also **"**x^y**"** button and **"**=**"** button.
There is also **textBox3** for your result.

Now what you have to do is make sure if provided numbers are correct, by checking if they aren't equal to string.empty, etc.

If you're sure, you can use simple:

```
int integer1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
int integer2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

textBox3.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(integer1 , integer2 )).ToString();
```

It works for me, check it.

BUT

Update:

If your calculator only has one textBox, you can do the same:

```
int indexOfPower = textBox3.Text.IndexOf("^");
int integer1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, indexOfPower));
int integer2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text.Substring(indexOfPower+1));

textBox3.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(integer1, integer2)).ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Hunter! thanks for the response. The calculator only has one textBox unfortunately.

Comment: Answer updated!

Comment: Did you find it helpful? @ErnestoRiera